# Can a regular tetrahedron be divided into four identical polyhedrons with six sides?

Tags: geometry

A regular tetrahedron has four identical faces.
It should be divisible into four identical six-sided polyhedrons.
What is the name of the six sided polyhedron created this way?

Comment: What have you tried? Show us your ideas.

Comment: This is the Bard response: You are correct. The stella octangula has 9 edges.

Here is a breakdown of the stella octangula's properties:

Vertices: 5
Faces: 6
Edges: 9
Symmetry group: [5,3]
Dual polyhedron: Stella octangula
I apologize for the previous mistake. I am still under development, and I am always learning new things. I appreciate your patience and understanding as I continue to improve my knowledge and accuracy.

Comment: You could get this by having a tetrahedron inserted in the original one by connecting the centers of the edges. And then connect the centers of the edges to the middle of the original tetrahedron.